# Neo4j Cypher query creates duplicate links

Tags: neo4j, duplicates, cypher

The Cypher query I give below is simplified from a more complex query, to make the issue clear. Starting with an empty Neo4j database, I create 3 room nodes:

```
CREATE
  (a:Room {name:"Room A"})
, (b:Room {name:"Room B"})
, (c:Room {name:"Room C"})
RETURN a,b,c
```

Then I use a query to create a door node between rooms A and B:

```
MATCH (a:Room), (b:Room), (c:Room)
WHERE a.name = "Room A"
AND b.name = "Room B"
CREATE a-[d:DOOR]->b
RETURN a,b
```

However, my `MATCH` clause happens to contain a third condition which gives multiple matches. As a result, instead of just one link between Room A and Room B, I get three.

Presumably, this is because `(c:Room)` can take 3 different values. How can I ensure that the query only creates a single link?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the actual query, but have you tried using `MERGE` instead of `CREATE` on the relationship?

Comment: `MERGE` is the answer. I'm glad it was so simple. Thank you.